# Could Euclid have bisected a line segment without his method of superposition?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, math-history, geometric-construction

In Book I Proposition 10 of the Elements, Euclid performs the bisection (i.e. finding a midpoint) of a line segment.  In the course of doing so, he uses Book I Proposition 4, the Side-Angle-Side Theorem, which proved with his controversial method of superposition.  My question is, could Euclid have proven Book I Proposition 10 without relying on Book I Proposition 4, so that the result wouldn't depend on the method of superposition?

The reason I ask is that I think I've found a simpler proof of Euclid's Book I Proposition 2 (involving the transferring of distances), but it relies on bisection, so I'm hoping that I'm not implicitly using the method of superposition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: See [Book I Proposition 9](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI9.html). Euclid could have made the reasoning for $n=2$ which would not resort to bissection.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard If you trace the propositions that Book VI Proposition 9 depends on, it eventually comes back to Book I Proposition 4.

Comment: [This](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/elements.html) is a helpful source for those that are searching the Prepositions of the Elements, so I'll leave it here for now.

Comment: I think you can prove it without using proposition 4, hilbert concluded that proposition 4 was not needed at all see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms but Euclid was not complete in his axiomatisation

Comment: @Willemien Hilbert's axioms do include a side-angle-side postulate (III.6 in Wikipedia's numbering), but are you saying that Hilbert does not use that postulate in his proof that you can bisect a line segment?  Do you have a page number or theorem number for Hilbert's proof in the Foundations of Geometry?

Comment: correction of my earlier comment 

I misunderstood the question, I thought it was about Postulate 4 (all right angles are equal) which is not needed.  I blame the question :) Off course you can do it without using postulate 4 , (just replace postulate 4 by its proof) , the question is more can you proof postulate 10 without using superposition, what boils down to "can you move angles?" but then what is the difference between moving a line segment,(allowed)  and moving an angle?, you get into a study of variable constant curvature planes (simplest form a torus)

Answer (score 0):

The unavoidable step in the proof is the principle that opposite sides of a parallelogram are equal.

In Euclidean geometry this is proved using the congruence axiom that you want to avoid, but really it is a weaker principle from the subsystem of affine geometry that does not include the concepts of angle or rotation.  In effect it is the Euclidean axiom restricted to superpositions that are parallel translations. (Maybe 180 degree rotations could be implicitly needed for some arguments, but they are avoidable for the midpoint proof by using a chain of several parallelograms, and they might be avoidable in general).

The two subsegments on either side of the midpoint are different geometric objects, and without some comparison principle no relation between them can be proved.  There would be one segment divided into two parts but no other facts derivable.  The minimal sufficient principle is the one about parallelograms.

Comment: How would you prove the result using only the principle that opposite sides of a parallelogram are equal?

Comment: Take a parallelogram with the segment as one of its diagonals, and draw lines parallel to the diagonals through all four vertices.  In the resulting figure the principle can be applied several times to get a chain of equalities that connect the two sub-segments.

Comment: Could you spell your proof out, preferably with a picture?  I'm having trouble visualizing this.

Comment: Take a parallelogram $P$ and the 4 midpoints of its sides, which are vertices of a second parallelogram $P'$.  This is to be set up so that one of the diagonals of $P'$ is the segment to be bisected (pick any point not collinear with the segment as a third vertex of $P'$, and complete the diagram as described using parallel lines).  In the figure consisting of $P$, $P'$ and the diagonals of $P'$, several applications of the equality principle for parallel segments produce a chain of equalities between the left and right half of the bisected segment.

Comment: Note that in the preceding comment, the word "midpoint" is used only to make it definite what the diagram will look like.  To construct the diagram, from segment to $P'$ to $P$, does not require the ability to construct midpoints.